# Register form in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, and want to create register form. I get error NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'register' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<register_id>[^/]+)/$'].

Please help me.

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_pasword = (user_form.cleaned_data['Password'])
            new_user.save()
            return render(request, 'main/account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
        else:
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
            return render(request, "main/account/register.html", {'user_form': user_form})
```

**url.py**

```
path("<int:register>/",views.register, name='register'),
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta():
    model = User
    fields = {"Username", "email", "Name", "SurName"}
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != ["password2"]:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password dont match")
        return cd["password2"]
```

**base.html**

```
<a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" method="POST" href="{% url 'register' %}">Регистрация</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py, replace "int:register/" to any string like

```
path("register/",views.register, name='register')
```

You view.py should be,

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, "main/account/register.html", {'user_form': user_form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # your existing codeof POST method
```

Comment: Than I get another error in register page. "ValueError at /register/

The view main.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: @MRXD  I think your view is not implemented for GET request method. I edited the anwser (adding view function for GET method).

Comment: I get new error: 
ValueError at /register/

ModelForm has no model class specified.

Comment: @MRXD replace ```class Meta():``` to ```class Meta:```

Comment: Nope.I get this error again..

"Exception Type: ValueError at /register/
Exception Value: ModelForm has no model class specified."

Comment: One another error in your code, fields should be list or tuple ```fields = ["Username", "email", "Name", "SurName"]```

Comment: Nope,I get this error again ,I'd rather create another registration form than use this.